# Shipping cost are reduced and they are reducing the total price not increasing it

Tags: product, checkout, extensions, shipping, bug

My store is located in Germany and if a customer lives in the USA he has to pay different shipping cost. To adjust those cost I'm using the extension MatrixRate. So here is my problem:

If the customer in the USA and want the product to get shipped there he has to pay 16.80€ for the shippment. But the store shows 14.12 € for the shipping cost. Also the product price will get **reduced**. Normally my product cost 79.90€ and suddenly it will show that it cost only 67,14 €. So the costumer has to pay 81,26 € instead of 97.60€.

If the costumer picks Germany as delivery address first and then switches to the USA he will get correct numbers. What can cause this problem?